# How better organize React-components interactions?

Tags: reactjs

I am building SPA with React and have the following structure of UI-components:

- App (base layout with navbars and footers)

  - EventsIndex (Load Events data from API)

    - FilterBar (common components where current filter settings is shown)
    - EventsTable (show Events data for desktop)
    - EventsAccordion (show Events data for mobiles)
  - SomeOtherIndex...

EventsTable and EventsAccordion have a lot of common logic such as pagination, filter's and sorting's handlers.

I have to lift up handlers from child components(EventsTable and EventsAccordion) to parent EventsIndex. But for me it seems not the best way.

Am i wrong?

What the best practice in such cases?

Should i use Redux? If no, when it better to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is all about **Components**, I would say the most important part when starting to design a **React App** is structuring your Components well.

**There are different ways to structure your components well, below are some:**

1. **Container Components:** When designing your app identify the container components, these are the components which are going to hold **state** and also manipulate them based on events.

   Coming to your question: ***I have to lift up handlers from child components(EventsTable and EventsAccordion) to parent EventsIndex. But for me, it seems not the best way. Should I use Redux?***

   **Answer:** When using container components only a few components are going to deal with the state and any child hierarchy ( Child Components ) are going to be **stateless** components / **( Functional Components )**, so in order to update the state they will have to have handlers passed down by their Container Components, using which these components are going to update state. ( **This is absolutely fine, that's the way it should be** )

   Coming to **REDUX**, using REDUX in such small scenario is not recommended, I would not recommend it, because it would be an overkill, REDUX is apt in a much complex scenario when you would like to share some **state** between two component trees, but still you could use REDUX but its just that, its not recommended.
2. **HOC ( Higher Order Components  ):** Whenever you have some functionality which is reusable, consider creating a HOC

   Please check : [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)
3. **Break Components to Smaller Re-useable pieces:** This is often very important whenever you see that a component contains code which is used elsewhere, go ahead and make it a **Separate Component**, thus making it **Reusable**.

Please check this, this has a bunch of best practices 
https://www.toptal.com/react/tips-and-practices

**When to use REDUX ?**

Basically, you need to be using REDUX, when ***keeping the state in a top-level root component is no longer sufficient***, like for **example :** (  you have two branches out from root component, one of the child component in branch A wants to access some state in branch B's child, then you need to move it to the root component and again pass it down, such cases are apt for **REDUX** ).

[image]

Please check this source: https://redux.js.org/faq/general#when-should-i-use-redux

Comment: Thx, can u explain on example(s) in which cases i should use Redux?

Comment: @nuT707 I have edited my answer, please check When to use REDUX

Comment: Thx a lot! Good explaining and helpful links!

Comment: Happy to help 

Answer (score 1):

You can follow a container type implementation - which means that if there is some common logic between components, they can be encapsulated within a component that acts as a container for these two components and provides the necessary common logic / data.

So, for example in your case it'll be something on the lines of

```
- EventsIndex (Load Events data from API)
    - FilterBar (common components where current filter settings is shown)
    - EventContainer (where common logic resides for both your components)
              - EventsTable (show Events data for desktop)
              - EventsAccordion (show Events data for mobiles)
```

where `EventContainer` provides the common props such as pagination, filter's and sorting's handlers.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The best approach that we follow in a team setting (and is opinionated; and probably won't fit in everyone's scenario) is to break the app into logical structures.

```
- src
  - Utils (reusable methods such as sorting, pagination, etc)
  - UI (Reusable UI components such as buttons, modals, etc)
  - Services (API Calls to the database, further divided by entities /users /posts etc)
  - Components (Hierarchy of components)
    - EventsIndex (uses the service directory to make API calls)
      - EventsIndexContainer (if following container encapsulation pattern)
        - EventsTable 
        - EventsAccordion
```

If the handler isn't component specific, I'd suggest move it to the utils folder (so that you have a single responsibility pattern as well as a single place to modify your logic rather than in two places) and pass down the handler to the table and accordion from the EventsIndex component or a EventsIndexContainer component that further encapsulates your logical components (the later one is preferred my many who I've worked with).